# So I am not allowed to report a bug against radeon driver because "natty is complete"?

Tags: radeon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does ubuntu-bug imply that I shouldn't report bugs for Compiz and Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39358/why-does-ubuntu-bug-imply-that-i-shouldnt-report-bugs-for-compiz-and-unity)

I was thinking about submitting three different bug reports for all three different graphical glitches I have found so far in Ubuntu 11.04. And now after running ubuntu-bug xserver-xorg-video-radeon I am discouraged to report "technical problems".

I feel lost, what am I supposed to do?

Comment: This is a bug in the apport hook, the wording is being changed and will be deployed in an update, sorry for the confusion!